# How to connect separate bones into one armature without moving them? (not parenting)

Tags: armature, bones

I have 3 bones in very specific locations, and I want to connect them.
Is there a way to connect them with additional bones without moving the positions of the original ones?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Select the head and the tail you want to connect and press F.

Comment: OMG. Thanks. I couldn't fathom that it could be that simple :D